# What libraries are available to convert the object representation to JSON/XML in presentation layer?

Tags: java, json, web-applications, jboss, resteasy

I am currently working on a web project where my `@Entity` looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "variable")
@XmlRootElement
public class Variable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private VariableType type;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String units;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false)
    private Date createdOn;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "retired_on", nullable = true)
    private Date retiredOn;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean core;
}
```

To convert this object into JSON, I am wiring up my entity with `@XmlRootElement` which binds it to `JAXB`

My `REST` call method looks like

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getVariables() {
        return Response.ok(variableManager.getVariables()).build();
    }
```

This approach has some problems:

1. It tightly couples an persistence to presentation layer. If something changes in backend, it will cause/expose the same thing on presentation layer. NOT DESIRABLE
2. The return data on presentation layer could be less/more(composite of another objects) data than the entity which is not feasible in this case

in a typical web application layer, there are usually 3 layers

```
presentation/
business/
persistence/
```

The decision of defining presentation, converting objects to JSON/XML should be on presentation layer. I am looking for ways I can convert my objects to `XML/JSON` without binding them to  persistence layer using `@XmlRootElement`

Please share you thoughts

Comment: It's not clear to me how this tightly couples persistence to presentation.  Are you saying you don't like that the entity has a `@XmlRootElement` annotation?  If that's not it, could you elaborate on that comment a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

1. In a web application, the three layers you specified, presentation, business, and persistence, all depend on the ones below it. Business layer classes uses services from the persistence layer. Presentation services uses business services. They can also access persistence services. If you chance your business objects, it's unavoidable that you will have to change any service in your presentation that is using it.
2. In the case you want to mix objects of different types, you'll most likely have to use your own serializer.

For XML, you have JAXB. For JSON, you can use anything from [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

I believe the JAX-RS that you're using, uses Jackson to serialize your returned object to JSON.

If you don't want to annotate your `Variable` class with XML and JSON annotations that you will only ever use in the Presentation layer, you can extract your class' interface, ie. make an interface `VariableInterface` with methods for the getters. Make your `Variable` class implement it and annotate it only with JPA annotations. These go in your Business layer. In your presentation, create a class `PresentationVariable` that implements `VariableInterface`. This way the dependency is from presentation to business. You then annotate your `PresentationVariable` with JSON/XML mapping annotations. Your logic in the presentation will have to convert your `Variable` to `PresentationVariable` through a constructor or a utility method and then you can return that.

```
package business;

public interface VariableInterface {
    long getId();
    String getName();
    //more
}

@Table
public class Variable implements VariableInterface {
    @Id
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String name; 
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public long getName() {
        return name
    }
}

package presentation;

import business.VariableInterface;

public class PresentationVariable implements VariableInterface {
    @XmlElement
    private long id;
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public long getName() {
        return name
    }
}
```